# Fetching logged user information in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

We have a requirement to enable drag and drop of content from Alfresco to a PLM application. Now we have created a new custom view with the PLM product and have incorporated an SWT browser in that view. The idea is that the user would enter the alfresco url and he would be able to drag and drop contents from Alfresco to PLM product using this new view.

The trouble here is that we are being asked to develop it as a single sign on application. The moment the URL is entered by the user, alfresco would ask the user his login credentials.
The user authenticates himself and would be able to view different documents.

But in order to actually download them, we need to set the user info. specifically the user name and password in the request to Alfresco. This is where we got stuck.

Is it possible to get a session or an equivalent identifier codefully [ Note that user visited alfresco url and has authenticated himself. So, we dont have any hold of his information there. ].

Requesting you to share any ideas...

Thanks,
Pavan.

Note:  A new UI that would prompt the user to enter user name and password might be possible. But we do not want to resort to that approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, some background.

Most web SSO systems work by authenticating the user themselves, and then setting a custom HTTP header containing the user identify (normally a plain username) which is sent to your web applications by a proxy. I'm not sure if that would work for you, but you may wish to investigate [integrating CAS with Alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service_Configuration), assuming that both your applications are webapps.

Other options for SSO with Alfresco which might work for non-webapps are NTLM (old and insecure) and Kerberos (much more secure; recommended). These normally integrate with your operating system login session but must be configured in the user's web browser as well as in all the applications that you wish to SSO enable.

In summary, there are a few options that may be available but it depends on the nature of the second application that you want to integrate Alfresco with. I would suggest that you do some further technical investigation based on these areas and any others which others might suggest, and then come back with any specific questions that you have.